# List output as a variable within a forloop function changes

Tags: list-manipulation, variable

[image: Population Data]

The above image shows my code. The graph plots my results for two different values of the variable "guards" (1000 and 200), having first produced lists of these figures. What I want is for mathematica to produce a series of these output lists for every value of "guards" between 0 and 1000 (they don't have to be graphed). Any idea how I automate this?

Comment: Please post your code (not image).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few remarks first:

1. Don't use `For` for [various reasons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica).
2. Don't start variable name with uppercase (could be internal MMA symbol).

It looks like your code calculates a recursive sequence of $S_n$ and then plots it vs $n$. Your $S_n$ depends on some parameters and  $S_{n-1}$, so $S_n=f(q,S_{n-1})$. For simplicity I assume that you have just one parameter $q$. I will also assume that your $f(q,s)=sq+q$. You can plug your real function with lovely `ArcTan` later.

When dealing with recursive sequences `FoldList` and `NestList` are often useful.
Consider following code:

```
f[q_, s_] := s q + q;
g[q_][{t_, s_}] := {t + 1, f[q, s]};
pop[q_, T_] := NestList[g[q], {0, 0}, T];
```

Function $g(q)$ has parameter $q$ and acts on pair $(t,S_n) \rightarrow (t+1,S_{n+1})$. After plugging $g$ into `NestList` we generate a list of pairs that you want to plot.

Thus `pop[q_,T_]` is a function that returns a list of pairs with  $T+1$ elements. Now plotting is easy, since we just call `pop` with different parameters.

```
ListPlot[Table[pop[i, 50], {i, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's worked like a charm.